# dplyr mutate combined with replace: why does replace fail to identify the condition?

Tags: r, replace, dplyr

I have these data called msa:

```
BN  MC
1   1A
2   2  
3   1B
4   4
5   2
```

and I want to perform the following:

```
  lala<-msa%>%
  mutate(mc=replace(mc, (mc=="1A"|mc=="1B"),50))%>%
  mutate(df= NA)%>%
  mutate(df=replace(df, mc> 3, 1))%>%
  as.data.frame()
```

it works,

```
BN  MC  df
1   50   1
2   2    NA
3   50   1
4   4    1
5   2    NA
```

however, if instead of 50 I replace with 10, or 100, or 1000, using the same code above:

```
 lala<-msa%>%
  mutate(mc=replace(mc, (mc=="1A"|mc=="1B"),10))%>%
  mutate(df= NA)%>%
  mutate(df=replace(df, mc> 3, 1))%>%
  as.data.frame()
```

I get:

```
  BN  MC  df
1   50   NA
2   2    NA
3   50   NA
4   4    1
5   2    NA
```

Why 'replace' seems to read only the first digit to make a decision on replacing or not?

---

EDIT
Working code based on MKR answer

```
lala<-msa%>%
  mutate(mc=replace(mc, (mc=="1A"|mc=="1B"),10))%>%

  lala[,]<-sapply(lala[,],as.numeric) #makes lala completely numeric

  lala<-mutate(lala,df= NA)%>%
  mutate(df=replace(df, mc> 3, 1))%>%
  as.data.frame()
```

Comment: My guess is that you run the `replace(..., 10)` on the same data frame **after** you run the `replace(..., 50)`. Hence there are no `1A` or `1B`...

Comment: Works fine for me

Comment: @Sotos No. Even if I am doing that, lala would be overwritten, so that is not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is that `MC` column is `chr` type. Hence MC is `coerced` to number during checking for `MC> 3`. (Only 1st character is `coerced`). Hence `100` will be as `1`. Any value like `50` or `80` on `MC` will make `MC > 3` as `TRUE` otherwise its `FALSE`. Where condition is evaluated as `TRUE` the value of `DF` is `1` otherwise its `NA`

```
msa%>%
  mutate(MC=replace(MC, (MC=="1A"|MC=="1B"),1000))%>%
  mutate(df= NA)%>%
  mutate(df=replace(df, MC> 3, 1))%>%
  as.data.frame()
```

Below test will help in understanding the problem.

```
> ch = "80"
> ch > 3
[1] TRUE
> ch = "100"
> ch > 3
[1] FALSE
```

Modifying the command by replacing `MC` as `as.numeric(MC)` will make it work for even 100.

```
msa%>%
  mutate(MC=replace(MC, (MC=="1A"|MC=="1B"),1000))%>%
  mutate(df= NA)%>%
  mutate(df=replace(df, as.numeric(MC)> 3, 1))%>%
  as.data.frame()

#  BN   MC df
#1  1 1000  1
#2  2    2 NA
#3  3 1000  1
#4  4    4  1
#5  5    2 NA
```

Comment: this solves the mystery. I have edited my question (at the end) to show how I finally coded based on your answer. Thank you